# Cannot link back to MVC view via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an *Index* View and when I click the *Edit* button, I post to the *Edit* View (via the Controller) and display a bootstrap modal popup.

By posting to the *Edit* View, the Controller/View automatically handle getting and displaying the correct data on the modal popup.

Once I'm on my *Edit* View with the dialog box appearing and I click on the *Close* button, I simply want to **link back** to the *Index* page again; but instead, am getting an error with the path of the url. The new path I want to link to is being "*tacked on*" to the original path instead of **replacing** it.

I'm using the *Url.Action* method inside the click event of the *Close* button (of which I verified it's hitting) and have verified the location.href url is exactly what is in the url variable as you see in the code.

What do I need to do to correctly link back to the *Index* url?

### Index View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Category", new { area="Categories", id = item.CategoryID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>Edit</a>
```

### Edit Controller

```
// GET: Categories/Edit/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(short id)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Category category = await db.GetCategoryIDAsync(id);

    if (category == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

### Edit View

```
@model YeagerTechDB.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="modal" id="categoryEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="categoryModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="categoryModal-label">Category Description</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryDescription, new { @class = "control-label required col-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" })
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryDescription, new { @class = "form-control" } )
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseCategory">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveCategory">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.Hidden("categoryEditUrl", Url.Action("Edit", "Category", new { area = "Categories" }))
    @Html.Hidden("catID", Model.CategoryID)
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            if (typeof contentEditCategory == "function")
                contentEditCategory()
        });
    </script>
}
```

### JS for Edit View

```
$('#btnCloseCategory').click(function (e)
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Category", new { area = "Categories" })';
    location.href = url;

    return false;
});
```

### Image of modal popup

[image]

### Image of error

[image]

Comment: Is your JS in an external file? If so, it won't go through the Razor engine and turn @Url.Action into an actual URL. Put the JavaScript in the View or hardcode the value in the external file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your javascript is in an external file you could do the following:

Attach the url to your button within your view with a data attribute as follows:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseCategory" 
data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Category", new { area = "Categories" })">Close</button>
```

Then pull back the url with the `data` method as follows:

```
$('#btnCloseCategory').click(function (e)
{
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    location.href = url;

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Great post... Worked great. You must have a lot of experience with MVC & Razor. Great to know this technique for the future!

Comment: btw, the JS is in an external file.

Comment: @sagesky36 No probs. I use that technique to pass most data to external js. I'm sure I learnt it on here. Great place to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing type="submit" to type="button" for your Close button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseCategory">Close</button>
```